# convert to selnium java for loop code in python selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, python

```
System.out.println("****************Scrolled down starts****************");

Thread.sleep(2000);

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

JavascriptExecutor ja = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

ja.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,350)", "");

Thread.sleep(500);

System.out.println("Scrolled time: " + i);

}

System.out.println("****************Scrolled down end****************");



System.out.println("****************Scrolled up starts****************");

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

JavascriptExecutor jb = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

jb.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-350)", "");

Thread.sleep(500);

System.out.println("Scrolled time: -" + i);

}
```

Here is my code i have write code in python also but it did not scroll my page

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
print("***********************Scrolled down starts***************")
for i in range(25):
    driver.execute_script("document.body.scrollTo(0, 350);")


print("*************************scrolling down end**********************")


print("**************************************Scrolled up starts****************")

for i in range(25):
    driver.execute_script("document.body.scrollTo(0, -350);")
print("scrolling down: - " + str(i))
```

Comment: Hi Arslan, please do not use answers as comments. The workflow on Stack Exchange is slightly different than a typical forum. Thanks!

Comment: I am also looking for this very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using driver.execute_script("document.body.scrollTo(0, -350);"

scrollTO will scroll to specified pixel positon , it is a one time operation as the body lenght and width remains the same.

IF you want to scroll continously use : ScrollBy

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.scrollBy(0, 350);"   #down
driver.execute_script("document.body.scrollBy(0, -350);"  #up
```

**Code:**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
print("***********************Scrolled down starts***************")
for i in range(25):
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("document.body.scrollTo(0, 350);")


print("*************************scrolling down end**********************")


print("**************************************Scrolled up starts****************")

for i in range(25):
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("document.body.scrollTo(0, -350);")
    print("scrolling down: - " + str(i))
```

Comment: i have changed it but did not work

Comment: in java it work fine but did not understand why it did not work in python kindly check and tell me how we write code that work fine

Comment: @ArslanHassan what you mean by it didn't work, i just ran the code and it works.

Comment: in console it show no error but did not scroll page kindly once run it on our compute this code and then tell me what is the problem

Comment: i ran your code only just add time.sleep(5) in the loop , it happens so fast that you wn't notice the scroll

Comment: it run but i want to run it slowly as it run in java slightly slow first time it scroll 350 and then again continue loop and then again scroll 350 and so on and then scrolling up word have you any way like this

Comment: @ArslanHassan added full code , in java it has thread.sleep(500) , in python use time.sleep(0.5)

Comment: it works Thank you

Comment: hi kindly looks this onces website it did not work    https://catevolution.com.au/litter-robot-3-connect.html

Comment: @ArslanHassan use window.scrollBy(0, 350); for that website instead of document.bpdy

Comment: hi, how can I print the number of scrolling in the console output like if it scrolls 1 first time then it shows in console 1 and then 2 and so on? I have written a method it runs correctly but in console, it shows "None"

Comment: print(driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 350);"+ str(i)))     Here is a method .

Answer (score 0):

In the Java code you are using `.scrollBy()` but in your python code you are using `.scrollTo()`. My guess is that it is not scrolling because of this mixup. Try changing the python code to use `.scrollBy()` method